# isomorphic-unfetch throws 400 bad request in react component of NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, isomorphic-fetch-api

I am trying to get some data from API in a React component in Next.js on the onChange event of a select box. I am using the isomorphic-unfetch module to make the hit on external API. But every time I make this hit I receive a 400 bad request. I have tried that hit with the same set of data on postman and it works right but just not in my code.

**Edit: I have just found out that the JSON data which is written after the declaration of the URL to hit is not being sent. I mean that in this**

```
fetch("https://loyalty.xgate.com/customer/w1/redeemable_cash_preview", {
        method: 'POST',
        formData : hitData,
        headers: {
          "Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      })
```

**Only the URL https://loyalty.xgate.com/customer/w1/redeemable_cash_preview is being hit but the method or formData or headers are not going with the request.**

This is the component I am using.

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import css from '../../redeemPopUp.css';
    import Link from 'next/link';
    import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
    import CashPreview from '../../pages/cashPreview';

    class Preview extends Component {
        state = {
            value: ""
          }

        cash = (id, event) =>{

          var hitData = {
            "account_id": "XXXX",
            "username": "XXXX",
            "password": "XXXX",
            "code": id,
            "points_to_redeem":event.target.value
          };

          fetch("https://loyalty.xgate.com/customer/w1/redeemable_cash_preview", {
            method: 'POST',
            formData : hitData,
            headers: {
              "Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
          })
          .then(function (result){
            console.log(result)        
          }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
        }


        render() { 
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className={css.modal_body}>

                    <div className={css.loyalty_row}>
                        <label

 className={css.tier_label} >Redeem Points:</label>
                    <select name="redeemPoints" onChange={(e)=>this.cash(this.props.id, e)}>
                        <option value="25000">25000</option>
                        <option value="20000">20000</option>
                        <option value="15000">15000</option>
                        <option value="10000">10000</option>
                        <option value="5000">5000</option>
                    </select>
                    {/* <div className={css.sep_line}></div> */}
                </div>
                <div className={css.loyalty_row}>
                    <label className={css.tier_label} >Redeem Points:</label>
                    <span className={css.tier_values}><strong>{this.state.value}</strong></span>      
                    <div className={css.sep_line}></div>
                </div>


                <div className={css.modal_footer}>
                    <Link href="#"><a href="#" className={css.btn} id="btn_ingresar">Redeem Points</a></Link>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Preview;
```

This is my nextJs page

```
import Preview from "../components/Preview/Preview";
import {withRouter} from "next/router";  

const CashPreview = (props) =>{
    const {router} = props;
    console.log(router)
    return (
        <div>
            <Preview id= {router.query.id}/>
        </div>
    )
};

export default withRouter(CashPreview)
```

Here is the image of what i am getting in response.
[image]

Comment: what `console.log(router.query.id)` return ?

Comment: That gives me an Id i am passing to this page in url

Comment: can you post the doc link for the API?

Comment: this is a private API. It doesn't have any online documentation. I am in contact with them to check the logs.

Comment: I think that you should contact them

Comment: Yes but I think it is not taking my Json containing headers and body etc.

Answer (score 0):

add below code in your root file(app.js) of express app

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  next();
});
```

Comment: didn't work bro. It's still throwing me the same error. I am uploading the image of the error with what it is passing me back.

Comment: No, I meant on my question I have uploaded an image to explain more.

Comment: oh,may be its cors error.you have to allow your client ip

Comment: I have used the same API in the expressJs app with request-promise in the same app. It didn't through any error there.

Comment: I turned on the cors plugin in my chrome browser as well.. Its still same.

Comment: yeah, if its express app you don't need cors but in react app you have separate server so it is not allowing to access api

Comment: Yeah I thought so too but even turning on the cors give me same error.

Comment: Do you think it could be possible that the headers and data are not being sent by fetch?

Comment: I used **isomorphic-fetch** in nextjs instead of **isomorphic-unfetch** and it works fine without headers